# removing applications in Mac using command

Tags: bash, macos, shell, command, sh

I have run this command and its working

```
cd /Applications/
sudo rm -rf Anydesk.app/
```

but I wanted the command to check if user is having the app or not. if yes then let the command run.
Also I want the command to return codes: return 0 for success (app successful delete), 1 for failure (app did not delete)

Answer (score 0):

You could test if the directory exists with something like

```
DIR=/Applications/Anydesk.app

if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
    echo "Deleting $FILE"
    sudo rm -rf $DIR
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `-f` means that `rm` may have a 0 exit status whether or not `$DIR` is successfully removed. If you're going to use `-f`, you'll need to test again if `$DIR` still exists.

Comment: where is -f I cannot see it in the command, also can I change the name of dir or it should be same sa the command?